# Should I play the previous Far Cry games to understand the storyline?

Tags: far-cry-series

I'm planning to play Far Cry 4 soon.

Should I play the previous games in this series to catch up with the story line?

Or is it an individual story of it's own?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202541/whats-the-link-between-the-different-game-in-the-far-cry-series?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The each game has an individual, unrelated to each other story. You're not missing out on any story details by skipping previous games.