# What's the link between the different games in the Far Cry series?

Tags: far-cry-series

Is there a link between the games in the *Far Cry* series?

The only "confirmed" link I can find is that *Far Cry 4* takes place after *Far Cry 3* as it shares characters ([Hurk](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Hurk) and [Willis](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Willis_Huntley)) and refers to events in the previous games (Hurk's monkey exploits). Otherwise, I couldn't find any "confirmed" links, aside from "wide beliefs" that [the first game's protagonist is the second game's antagonist](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Carver#Trivia).

Is there any "chronology" to the series?

Comment: I personally never saw any connection to any of the games in the series. They are all pretty independent of each other. Their attempt to refer to the last game seemed forced, in some kind of attempt to connect the 2 together, which had no connection imo. 3 and 4's game play was pretty much the same.

Comment: Willis also makes a reference to Jason from FC3, in FC4.

Comment: No, there is no connection what so ever. If you have finished the game then you know that Hurk mentions Jason from FC 3 in the mission **A Familiar Feeling**, but nothing else is mentioned. And he hinted that next game can be in China or some other Buddhist country.

Comment: Related: https://youtu.be/0Zlh_eibKpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no real confirmed connection between any of the games. I have heard that the lost letters in Far Cry 3 reference back to the older games, but other than that, the one you mentioned, and some random "claimed" connections, there is no actual progression within the series.

Answer (score 3):

> I couldn't find any "confirmed" links, aside from "wide beliefs" that [the first game's protagonist is the second game's antagonist](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Carver#Trivia).

Clint Hocking, Far Cry 2's Creative Director confirms the above fan speculation in the Oct. 2021 IGN article, [How Far Cry's Iconic Villains Were Created](https://www.ign.com/articles/how-far-cry-villains-were-created) (emphasis mine):

> ...But beyond the game’s
> story, there’s a fascinating history behind the Jackal that few people
> outside of the walls of Ubisoft know.
>
> **“The Jackal is actually supposed to be Jack Carver from the original
> Far Cry,” Hocking reveals, confirming a long-held fan theory.** Both
> Carver and the Jackal have a history in the US Navy, and – perhaps
> most tellingly – some texture files for the Jackal in Far Cry 2 are
> named after the original Far Cry protagonist. These details have
> convinced some fans that the two characters are related, but Hocking’s
> confirmation finally transforms the theory into fact.
>
> “Jack Carver in the original Far Cry was this shifty, smuggler, gun
> runner kind of crook,” says Hocking. “The idea was [the Jackal] is
> just him, 10 years later or something, after he's seen whatever he saw
> on this island [during the events of Far Cry]. Maybe it was drug
> induced, maybe it's post-traumatic stress disorder, or maybe it's
> real. But the idea is, a decade later, he has leveled up his smuggling
> game, and he's gotten embroiled in this conflict. But he's also been
> through a lot more and he's seen a lot of messed up stuff.”
>
> This fascinating origin story is, sadly, nowhere to be seen
> within the world of Far Cry 2. But despite his link to the original
> Far Cry only existing within the minds of the people who made him, The
> Jackal’s warped moral compass makes him a great villain in his own
> right. Compared to the bad guys who will succeed him, though, The
> Jackal’s role in Far Cry 2 is relatively straightforward.

Comment: [This new article](https://www.ign.com/articles/far-cry-2-fan-theroy-the-jackal-is-jack-carver) provides new details on this subject.

Comment: @vvilin That article's source is the article I cited in this answer.

Answer (score -3):

Jack Carver was the Jackal who survived the 2nd game and supplied weapons to both the pirates and the Golden Path with Longinus.

Comment: Do you have any proof to back up this claim?